# Correct way of handling (pending) intents in AppWidgets

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I have a question regarding AppWidget intent handling. I have a widget which is clickable, and on click I want to send an intent to the AppWidgetProvider itself for further processing.

**The problem: I receive the intents initially in onReceive(), but after a while (not sure what causes it), onReceive() is no longer called.**

I have the following code, all in MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider.

a) register for receiving broadcasts:

```
in onEnabled(...):
  context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(MY_ACTION));
```

b) set intent to be fired on click:

```
in onUpdate(...)
  Intent intent= new Intent(MY_ACTION);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0/*notusedanyway*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent);
```

c) react to event and do something:

```
in onReceive(...)
  if (MY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())
    doSomething();
```

When I deploy + add a widget, it works fine. However, after a while - not sure what exactly causes the problem, but a phone call, for example, seems to affect it - I no longer get any notifications in onReceive().

I am completely stumped why this is the case. Can someone point out to me the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a BroadcastReceiver registered in your AndroidManifest.xml file. When you register it in onEnable it is tied to the process. Whenever Android kills your process (for example, when a phone call is received) then your receiver no longer exists and (as you observed) no longer works.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I did some logging and my provider is in fact instantiated three times at startup already, but onEnabled is only called once. That is a big hint in the direction of "don't rely on any instance registration code..." ;)